# Young Tv-Show from 90s or 2000

Tags: story-identification, tv

I used to watch a live-action science fiction TV series about a young boy and his sister (named Rom).

They were taken to a Utopia place where they were obliged to take injections to make them always smiling but the brother run away and tries to save his sister. The brother has a protecting angel.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: it was a series real people not cartoon. as for the name it was Rom. I wanted just emphasize it coz I only remember hers.

Comment: Great, now work your way through the checklists and I'm sure we can come up with some more info to add

Comment: ah okay thanks for the guidance ! I started to like this site ^_^

Comment: When you say the brother has a protecting angel, do you mean there's literally a character (presumably with advanced abilities) who speaks and acts to protect the brother, or is it more of a "he gets lucky so many times he begins to believe there's an unseen force protecting him" situation?

Comment: the protecting angel is another charachter "little boy"